# Instantiating new objects in .NET Core that use dependency injection in their constructor without using new

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I've been trying to grasp the concept of Dependency Injection within .NET Core but have hit a problem. I think I'm missing the point somewhere along the line.

As an example, say I have a top level *GameHandler* class, then a *Game* class and a *ScoreCard* class.

My *Game* class has a dependency on the *ScoreCard* class and this needs to be registered as a transient service since each new game needs a new scorecard. I can achieve that by doing this...

```
public class Game
{
    private readonly IScoreCard _scoreCard;

    public Game(IScoreCard scoreCard)
    {
        _scoreCard = scoreCard;
    }
}
```

Then I register the service in startup.cs in the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddTransient<IScoreCard, ScoreCard>();
```

This is all good, it's a simple one to one relationship where the *Game* class needs a single instance of the *ScoreCard* class.

My *GameHandler* class also has a dependency on the *Game* class. However, in this case, I want to potentially have multiple games, probably stored in a dictionary of some sort along with a key. And I don't know how many I'll need because it depends on who is playing at a particular time so I'd need to create new Game objects whenever I need them.

If I try and do this using *new*, like this

```
Game _newGame = new Game();
```

it obviously doesn't work because my Game constructor now has the DI ScoreCard stuff in there and that doesn't match. So how do I create new instances of Game using DI without using *new*?

Comment: You're making the common mistake of conflating the idea of dependency injection with a dependency injection *framework*, the latter being entirely optional. `Game` needs an `IScoreCard`, that means it must be instantiated with one. Whether this is done with a DI framework is immaterial, but DI frameworks are not magic -- they will `new` up objects just like you would. If `GameHandler` cannot or should not directly create `Game` objects because it doesn't know about `IScoreCard`s, it should get a `Func<Game>` to create them on the fly, and you can pass `() => new Game(new ScoreCard())`.

Comment: @jon-clark Do you was able to solve this issue? I would be interested in a solution.

Answer (score 4):

At some point, you need a 'scope'.   That scope is a level in your code where your instances are created.   In some cases, the scope may be `main`, in message passing systems, each 'message' will have a new scope.

If your scope is 'every time a new game is created', then using whatever DI package you are using (I'm guessing it's the default net core one), then you need to call `IServiceProvider.CreateScope()`.  After this point, any time you ask the service provider to give you a new Game(), it will return one based on how each class was registered.

With dependency injection, you should never call `new`, you need to ask the service provider to give you an instance of a type.

```
 IServiceProvider.GetService<YourType>();
```

IServiceProvider can be retrieved either when you create it (after registration, and building), or it can actually be injected into a constructor too.

Comment: “any time you ask the service provider to give you a new Game()”.

How do I ask?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the new Game is returned by GetService, for example `var _newGame = IServiceProvider.GetService<IGame>();` where `IGame` is the interface to the Game class. The class `Game` and the interface `IGame` would have to be registered with the Dependency Injection engine.

Comment: What if my `Game` also needs some non-DI parameters, like a game configuration? Or a `Client` needing a UDP socket? Should I use a property for that instead of a ctor parameter and hope setting it is not forgotten after instantiating them from DI? Or should I create a factory for them which uses `ActivatorUtilities` together with those non-DI parameters?

Comment: I would generally use a factory pattern for that.  Like how HttpClientFactory creates an HttpClient for constructors that need one.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

In your case, `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Game>(yourServiceProvider);`.